# Prove the sum of large random variables to be infinity

Tags: real-analysis, probability

let $h_i$ to be i.i.d Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unity variance, that is
$$h_i \sim N(0,1)$$

Define a new variable $A=h_1^2+h_2^2...h_N^2$, in the case of $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Can we show that: for all $u>0$
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(A>u) \rightarrow 1$$

Intuitively, I think the statement is right because expectation of $A$, $E(A)=N$ approaching to infinity as N, and most of the possibility concentrates on the expectation. But I hope I can get strict proof.

Comment: I don't understand this: $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(A\rightarrow\infty) \rightarrow 1$. You, please edit. Suggestion: For all $u>0$ $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} P(A_N>u) = 1$

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I have modified my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: OK: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: well..My interest is in the sum of **square** of normal distribution, instead of sum of normal distribution.

Comment: Oh, yes! Then think of the central limit theorem. The sum of your independent variables is tending to a normal distribution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Maybe you can use that

a) A random variable $A=\sum_{1}^{n}h_i^2$, by definition, has distribution $\chi^2(n)$, n - degree of freedom

b)Limit distribution $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi^2(n)=N(n,2n)$

Comment: Thank you very much! I have achieved what I want.